# Upload multiple files in an Ajax call using file upload jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I understand that it is not possible to upload files using a regular Ajax call, so I would like to simulate the process using a jQuery file upload plugin. I have a form that allows users to enter data for an item that has 3 file inputs named male_image, female_image, and neutral_image. I would like to upload the files in all 3 inputs in the success callback of my Ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/manage/processadditem",
      data:  $("#add_form").serialize(),
      dataType: "html",
      success: function( response, textStatus, XHR )
      {
        if(response.indexOf('invalid') >= 0 || response.indexOf('Exception') >= 0){
            //Show them their errors
            alert(response);
        }
        else{
            //Data was good
            //Upload male_/female_/neutral_image to /manage/items/itemimage
            //for further processing
        }

      }
    });
```

I already have the code set up on the back side to handle the images, I just need to get them there. All of the multiple file input plugins I can find seem to handle sending multiple files from a single input. How can I send from multiple file inputs each with a single file so I can tell them apart on the back end?

Comment: Your understanding is a bit flawed, it's completely possible to upload  multiple files using AJAX. Here is an article: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Comment: @Vap0r It looks like fileReader is supported by just about every browser the site is targeting, but what about the FormData object?

Comment: It's been a good long while since I've had any experience with this. But I believe this is one of the most up-to-date methods of doing this, but I think you need an iframe fallback. You can just use jquery's file upload plugin, but I have no experience to help you with that. I just wanted to point out that you can in fact use AJAX to upload files. (That's what the jquery upload plugin does anyways!)

Comment: @Vap0r If the plugins are all doing the same thing I might as well use one of them instead of hard coding everything, and that gets me back to my original problem of not having any idea how to apply a plugin to multiple inputs rather than a single input which supports multiple files, since that's what all the results seem to pull up.

Comment: Like I said, I was just trying to show you that your assumption is wrong, are you using [this jQuery file uploader](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)? It has multiple file drag and drop AJAX upload built right into it. That might be what you want to use.

Comment: @Vap0r yeah, I was able to find an example on the wiki if using multiple file inputs on a single page, so I'm trying to modify it to work.

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't be more helpful, but write here or update your post if you come across any additional problems.

Comment: @Vap0r I have it in place and now I'm having trouble getting it to run properly. I have it posted in another question if you would like to take a look.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889459/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-no-method-fileupload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this [jquery upload](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress3.html) and upload multiple files, the example is very easy

Comment: I've been struggling with other plugins to do this for two days now and I got this one up and running in only a few minutes. Very easy to use.