# blueimp jQuery file upload not being triggered

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, blueimp

I'm trying to use the blueimp file upload plugin to asynchronously upload images but when I try to upload them nothing happens. None of the callback functions are being triggered at all. I'm using this function to bind the file uploader to the file inputs.

```
var initFileUpload = function (gender) {
//Used to bind fileupload plugin and send files

//bind file upload
$('#add_form').fileupload({
    namespace: gender+'_image',
    singleFileUploads: true,
    formData: [{name:'gender', value: gender}],
    fileInput: $("#"+gender+'_image'), 
    done: function(e, data){
        alert('success '+data.result);
    }

});
//Bind event callbacks
$('#add_form').bind('fileuploadsend', function (e, data) {
    console.log('sent');
});
$('#add_form').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    console.log('done');
});
$('#add_form').bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.result);
});
$('#add_form').bind('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.result);
});

}
```

Which was inspired by the multiple file upload tutorial [here.](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Input-Fields-in-one-Form-v4) I'm doing it this way because I have 3 different inputs with different names. I'm then firing the send function manually inside of my ajax call, or attempting to.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/manage/processadditem",
      data: $("#add_form").serialize(),
      dataType: "html",
      success: function( response, textStatus, XHR )
      {
        if(response.indexOf('invalid') >= 0 || response.indexOf('Exception') >= 0){
            //Show them their errors
            alert(response);
        }
        else{
            //Upload item images
            //Send files
            $('#add_form').fileupload('send', {fileInput: $("#neutral_image"), url: '/manage/items/itemimage/test' });
            $('#add_form').fileupload('send', {fileInput: $("#male_image"), url: '/manage/items/itemimage/test' });
            $('#add_form').fileupload('send', {fileInput: $("#female_image"), url: '/manage/items/itemimage/test' });
            alert('should have uploaded image to cdn.completeset.com/items/test_nla.jpg if gender was neutral');
        }

      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('An error occurred, please try again later.');
      }
    });
```

I found in the documentation [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API) under the section Programmatic File Uploads that you can use the send method to manually send files with a line like `$('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: filesList});` so that's what I'm trying to use to send the files. Unfortunately I'm not getting any sort of response from any of the callback functions at all, and I have no idea why.

Comment: make sure you aren't including jQuery.js twice. Also keep in mind that jQuery Tools sometimes includes it's own version of jQuery if you are using jQuery tools.

Comment: @KevinB That got rid of the error message, but now it's just silently failing. Do you know of any ways I might be able to get debug messages out of it?

Comment: Try binding to the fail event. `$('#add_form').on('fileuploadfail', func);` or `.bind` if using old jquery.

Comment: @KevinB I tried adding alerts to both the done and fail events, reflected in the code above, but neither has triggered. It does successfully make it past all 3 function calls to the alert though.

Comment: So binding to the `fileuploadfail` event of `#add_form` didn't give you an error? (not the one from your ajax)

Comment: Confirm that `$("#add_form")` selects an element, and that `$("[id=add_form")` only selects 1 element.

Comment: @KevinB I misinterpreted that the first time, but no, it's not getting triggered either. It seems like it's completely skipping over my function calls.

Comment: @KevinB only one element with id add_form. I also tried adding an alert to the start event and still got nothing.

Comment: Hey jaimerump, jumped over here from your other question. Is there anyway that we can see your code live?

Comment: @KevinB I've overhauled the question to reflect what I've figured out by playing with it. I'm pretty sure that the file uploader is being attached, because the function that is supposed to attach it is being fired correctly, but once it is attached it isn't doing anything at all.

Comment: @KevinB - that fixed it for me, I was including jquery twice

Answer (score 2):

I just ended up going with the malsup form plugin here. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm After struggling with blueImp for 2 days I got this one up and running in only a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can download working example here;

[jQuery Blueimp file uploader](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3)